# 404: {“errors”:[{“message”:”Sorry, that page does not exist”,”code”:34}]}

Tags: python, tweepy

I m trying to get 10 tweets made by a user using python tweepy.The code:

```
import tweepy

consumer_key=""
consumer_secret=""
access_token=""
access_token_secret=""

#authorise access to Twitter on our behalf
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)



usertweets=api.user_timeline(["username"],[10])
for tweet in usertweets:
    print (tweet.text)
```

If i give my own username it works but for some reason i dont get only 10 tweets but all the tweets i ve done and if i give as a username any other username i get this

> error:404: {“errors”:[{“message”:”Sorry, that page does not exist”,”code”:34}]}

The other usernames by the way exist.Also sometimes it doesnt give me an error when i use different username than mine but instead it prints my own tweets.Any idea what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you misunderstood the documentation. Square brackets in docs usually mean that an argument is optional. You can pass it, but you don't have to. You are not supposed to use `[]` in the real query. For example:

[API.user_timeline](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.user_timeline)

```
API.user_timeline([id/user_id/screen_name][, since_id][, max_id][, count][, page])
```

could be used that way:

```
usertweets=api.user_timeline(screen_name='some_user_name', count=10)
```

Comment: seems like you are right since when i changed that i dont get the error anymore..Why do i not get the right tweets though?Even though i put a strangers username i get the tweets of my username

Comment: The error you had was kinda obvious for me, but unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with this API. Maybe try different combinations? E.g. using id or user_id instead of screen_name? Maybe delete the keyword `screen_name=` and just use it as a positional argument: `api.user_timeline('some_user_name', count=10)`?